# Lock the android orientation as landscape throughout the App?

Tags: android

I have checked many question based on this but still I am not able to get it how to lock the screen orientation to landscape through out the app. ?

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:name=".BasicLayoutCheckActivity"
        />
```

this is not working for me it comes back to potrait if another activity is used

Comment: So why not adding it to the other activities as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Manifest, you can set the screenOrientation to `landscape for all the activities` . 
You have placed for `one activity` so other activities are opening in portrait, So for `fixing` set `all your activities with orientation` as your first activity.
It would look something like this in the XML:

```
<activity android:name=".BasicLayoutCheckActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the following in the `onCreate()` method:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Greetings!

Comment: This works better because this way I can use this only once in a base class and use it throughout the app. Adding xml tag to each Activity in the manifest is an ugly and error prone solution. I wonder why Android still hasn't introduced one single tag to set the orientation throughout the app.

Answer (score 4):

Hey check this out In the androidmanifest file inside activity add it

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to do this for every activity you can register an activity lifecycle callback in your custom application class (if you have one).

Something like...

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Lock orientation in landscape for all activities, yaay!
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);                  
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The orientation property has to be set to every individual activity of the application.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by another activity? The configuration is per activity. Say if your application has three activity then you must specify each one as landscape.